# More concise way to class match and access last of Option[List]

Tags: scala, refactoring

I have a function that as a parameter takes an object and if it is of the correct type I need to access the last element in an `Option[List[Int]]`. I have a working solution but it seems clumsy. In the case that there are not any items in `obj.listOfThings` I will need to have `i` have the value 0. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
val i = foo match {
  case obj: Bar =>
    obj.listOfInts match {
      case Some(ints) =>
        ints.last
      case _ =>
        0
    }
  case _ =>
    0
}
```

Technically it could return an `Option[Int]`. I'm still pretty new to Scala and would like to learn better approaches to this sort of problems.

Comment: You could avoid the second match with `obj.listOfInts.map(_.last).getOrElse(0)`.

Comment: Having the feeling that a solution is clumsy and needs improvement is a good sign that you are learning something. This might be more of a code-review question though..

Comment: @beefyhalo You actually are probably right and I wouldn't mind it being migrated there. I actually forgot that one even existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case initially it seems that what Ende Neu suggested is the right way to go:

```
val i = foo match {
  case obj: Bar =>
     obj.listOfInts.map(_.last /* This throws an exception when the list is empty*/).getOrElse(0)
  case _ =>
    0
}
```

But if you look into it you'll see that you have a bug in your code, in the case that that `obj.listOfInts is Some(Nil)`, because in that case you get a NoSuchElementException for trying to call last on an empty List.

Try this code with `foo = Bar(Some(Nil))` and see for yourself.

When you use Option[List] think very carefully if this is what you want.
Usually after some thinking you will scrap the Option and just stay with a List because the Option serves no purpose.
I worked with many developers who misuse Option[List] because of not understanding the similarities between Nil and None and usually the 'None' case ends up playing the same role as Some(Nil)

So you end up having to do this:

```
optionalList match {
    case None => // do something
    case Some(list) =>
        list match {
            case Nil => // do the same thing
            case head::tail => // do other stuff
        }
}
```

As you can see the None case and the Some(Nil) case are basically the same.

**To fix your bug you should do:**

```
  case class Bar(listOfInts: Option[List[Int]])

  val i = foo match {
    case Bar(Some(list)) if list != Nil => list.last
    case _ => 0
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't write the class but I will look to change that Option[List]. If I just make the option List[Int], I have another place that needs to know if its unassigned or empty. Currently it checks case None | Some(Nil). From my understanding of your post, I could get rid of the Option and just case Some(Nil)?

Comment: No, I meant that if it was all your code maybe you could just leave it as List[Int]. But now I see that you differentiate between the case of unassigned (None) and empty (Some(Nil)). I don't really know how bar is implemented so it's hard to answer but I'll try to add to my original answer.

Comment: You could prevent the `NoSuchElementException` on `Some(Nil)` using `listOfInts.flatMap(_.lastOption)`.

Comment: This is also nice but I find the pattern matching option way more simple and clear.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `flatMap` and `lastOption` here:

```
obj.listOfInts.flatMap(_.lastOption)
```

In case `listOfInts` is `None`, or it is `Some(Nil)`, this will return `None`.  Otherwise it will return the last element.  If you want to return `0` instead of `None`, just use `getOrElse`:

```
obj.listOfInts.flatMap(_.lastOption).getOrElse(0)
```

If you wanted to use a match, you could do:

```
obj.listOfInts match {
    case Some(list@(hd::tl)) => list.last
    case _ => 0
}
```

Here, the `hd::tl` guarantees that `list` is not empty.  Another option is use a conditional match:

```
obj.listOfInts match {
    case Some(list) if list.nonEmpty => list.last
    case _ => 0
}
```

Or to match the `None` and `Some(Nil)` cases first:

```
obj.listOfInts match {
    case None | Some(Nil) => 0
    case Some(list) => list.last
}
```

Comment: `s/probably/definitely`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, I think the best way to go is:

```
val i = foo match {
  case obj: Bar => obj.listOfInts.map(_.last).getOrElse(0)
  case _        => 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More concise way including the instanceof:

```
scala> case class B(is: Option[List[Int]])
defined class B

scala> def f(x: Any) = Option(x) collect { case b: B => b.is flatMap (_.lastOption) } flatten
f: (x: Any)Option[Int]

scala> f(B(Option(5 to 7 toList)))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(7)
```

or

```
scala> import PartialFunction.{ condOpt => when }
import PartialFunction.{condOpt=>when}

scala> def g(x: Any) = when(x) { case b: B => b.is flatMap (_.lastOption) } flatten
g: (x: Any)Option[Int]

scala> g(B(Option(5 to 7 toList)))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(7)
```

It's probably worth asking why you lost static type info, that you need to pattern match.

Comment: Its probably something that should be designed a little better but we have several different subtypes of a superclass which some have special attributes that are used in this function.